# Rijndael-128 ECB on PHP

Tags: php, encryption, ecb

I would like to know how can I do this on PHP:

```
Public Function DesencriptarRijndael(ByVal texto As String, ByVal key As String, ByRef Respuesta As Integer, ByRef Mensaje As String) As String
    Dim algoritmo As New System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged()
    Try
        algoritmo.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(key)
        algoritmo.Mode = CipherMode.ECB

        Dim decryptor As ICryptoTransform = algoritmo.CreateDecryptor()
        Dim data As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(texto)
        Dim dataDecrypted As Byte() = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length)
        Return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(dataDecrypted)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Respuesta = 7
        Mensaje = "Se esperaba la cadena de texto en formato encriptado"
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

This is the actual code with the one I'm trying:

```
<?php
function fn_cargarTexto()
{
    $filename = "Encriptado.txt";

    $textoCargado = "";

    $file = fopen($filename, "r");

    while(!feof($file))
    {
        $textoCargado = $textoCargado . fgets($file, 4096);
    } // Fin del while.

    fclose($file);

    return $textoCargado;
} // Fin de la función fn_cargarTexto.

$llave = "XtoDU1JaWgZWg18Qf1g96A==";
echo("llave" . " = " . $llave . "<br />");

$llave64 = base64_decode($llave);
echo("llave64" . " = " . $llave64 . "<br />");

$textoCargado = fn_cargarTexto();
echo("textoCargado" . " = " . $textoCargado . "<br />");

$textoCargado64 = base64_decode(textoCargado);
echo("textoCargado64" . " = " . $textoCargado64 . "<br />");

// 128 192 256

$algoritmoCifrado = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128;
echo("algoritmoCifrado" . " = " . $algoritmoCifrado . "<br />");

$modoCifrado = MCRYPT_MODE_ECB;
echo("modoCifrado" . " = " . $modoCifrado . "<br />");

$tamano = mcrypt_get_iv_size($algoritmoCifrado, $modoCifrado);
echo("tamano" . " = " . $tamano . "<br />");

$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($tamano, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);
echo("iv" . " = " . $iv . "<br />");

$resultado = mcrypt_decrypt($algoritmoCifrado, $llave, $textoCargado, $modoCifrado, $iv);
echo("resultado" . " = " . $resultado . "<br />");
```

?>

Comment: "this is the actual code with the one I'm trying" and what is the result?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the mcrypt library to use the Rijndael-128 encryption algorithm.

```
$td = mcrypt_module_open('Rijndael-128', '', 'ECB');
```

See https://www.php.net/mcrypt_module_open for examples

Comment: What's not working? What have you tried, and what is the output? I can't help you unless you provide details.

Comment: I have this file: http://www.jeanpaulruizvallejo.com/jeanpaul/arkix/tcc/serviciosWeb/Encriptado.txt. It contains a raw of data encrypted with Ridjndael-128 ECB mode from Visual Basic. I stored it on a file to make tests. Now I'm using this to decrypt it: http://www.jeanpaulruizvallejo.com/jeanpaul/arkix/tcc/serviciosWeb/Prueba07.php it goes like what you can show above.

Comment: I don't know if it is a codification issue or what, I feel crazy trying to solve this :(

Comment: It should return an XML with some locations descriptions on it.

Something like this:

<Ciudad>
    <CodCiudad>1</CodCiudad>
    <NombreCiudad>MEDELLIN</NombreCiudad>
    <NombreDepartamento>ANTIOQUIA</NombreDepartamento>
  </Ciudad>
  <Ciudad>

Comment: I meant, what have you tried in PHP, and what were the results of the said PHP. I need to see your implementation, not your use case..

Comment: Something that begins like this:

<Ciudad>
    <CodCiudad>1</CodCiudad>
    <NombreCiudad>MEDELLIN</NombreCiudad>
    <NombreDepartamento>ANTIOQUIA</NombreDepartamento>
  </Ciudad>
  <Ciudad>

Comment: Again... if you want help you need to provide your implementation, not the use case.

Comment: @Jean Paul, if your going to vote my answers down because you are incapable of providing the necessary information for someone trying to help you, then consider this my last attempt at replying to your questions. Yiesh.